Settings REST_FRAMEWORK error DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS configuration
I'm following along this tutorial. I added the "REST_FRAMEWORK" object how they describe in settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
  ),
}

I get this error after running command py manage.py runserver. Any help is greatly appreciated.


You put 'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema' into the 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' tuple.
How to fix:
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'
    ],
    # out of DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema' 
}


I updated my code to the above suggestion and now I'm seeing this error -->
ImportError: Could not import 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema' for API setting 'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS'. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'drf_spectacular'.

Added 'drf_spectacular' to INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'drf_spectacular',
] --> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'drf_spectacular'

@JasonSpence, are you sure you installed it with pip install drf-spectacular? Update your question with more details please.
